# Why my code ends even though i add a way to restart it

Tags: python, loops

Hello this is me again asking for a question about my code I am creating a Rock, Paper, Scissor i add 
`main()` and `def main():` and indent the code but when i run the code this happens

```
C:\Users\Timothy\Documents>python text.py

C:\Users\Timothy\Documents>
```

this is my code

```
def main():
    import random
    print("1=Rock, 2=Paper, 3=Scissor")
    player = int(input("Please Put your choice"))
    ai = random.randint(1,3)
        ###if and else statement for ai to print the random integer to string
    if (ai == 3):
        print("AI: Scissor")
    elif (ai == 2):
        print("AI: Paper")
    elif (ai == 1):
        print("AI: Rock")
            ####if and statement for the ai and player
    if (player == ai):
        print("It is a tie")
    if (player == 1 and ai == 2):
        print("AI won")
    if (player == 1 and ai == 3):
         print("You Won!!")
    if (player == 2 and ai == 1):
        print("You won")
    if (player == 2 and ai == 3):
        print("AI won")
    if (player == 3 and ai == 1):
        print("AI won")
    if (player == 3 and ai == 2):
        print("You won")

        main()
```

Comment: You indented `main()` a bit too much. It *shouldn't* be indented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to loop the program using `while True` so that the game can be played more than once.

```
def main():
    import random
    print("1=Rock, 2=Paper, 3=Scissor")
    player = int(input("Please Put your choice"))
    ai = random.randint(1,3)
        ###if and else statement for ai to print the random integer to string
    if (ai == 3):
        print("AI: Scissor")
    elif (ai == 2):
        print("AI: Paper")
    elif (ai == 1):
        print("AI: Rock")
            ####if and statement for the ai and player
    if (player == ai):
        print("It is a tie")
    if (player == 1 and ai == 2):
        print("AI won")
    if (player == 1 and ai == 3):
         print("You Won!!")
    if (player == 2 and ai == 1):
        print("You won")
    if (player == 2 and ai == 3):
        print("AI won")
    if (player == 3 and ai == 1):
        print("AI won")
    if (player == 3 and ai == 2):
        print("You won")


while True:
    main()
    restart = input("Again? Y/N: ").upper()
    if restart == "Y":
        main()
    if restart == "N":
        break
```

Comment: The solution with the `while` loop is fine (much better than the original solution with recursion) but you shouldn't call `main` if `restart == "Y"`. `main` is already called at the beginning of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Yup it is indented too much

```
def main():
    import random
    print("1=Rock, 2=Paper, 3=Scissor")
    player = int(input("Please Put your choice"))
    ai = random.randint(1,3)
        ###if and else statement for ai to print the random integer to string
    if (ai == 3):
        print("AI: Scissor")
    elif (ai == 2):
        print("AI: Paper")
    elif (ai == 1):
        print("AI: Rock")
            ####if and statement for the ai and player
    if (player == ai):
        print("It is a tie")
    if (player == 1 and ai == 2):
        print("AI won")
    if (player == 1 and ai == 3):
         print("You Won!!")
    if (player == 2 and ai == 1):
        print("You won")
    if (player == 2 and ai == 3):
        print("AI won")
    if (player == 3 and ai == 1):
        print("AI won")
    if (player == 3 and ai == 2):
        print("You won")

        main() # this way if will run if this condition is met player == 3 and ai == 2
    main() # this will surely run in the end calling itself
```

Comment: And now you fill up the stack by `main` calling `main` calling `main` calling `main` calling `main` ...

Comment: @Matthias It wont least for this simple program there is blocking input here `player = int(input("Please Put your choice"))`